# Not able to run the rpart program

Tags: r

I am running following program on R-studio:

```
risk <- read.csv(file = "H:/classifyrisk.txt", 
           header=TRUE,sep="\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
choose <- runif(dim(risk)[1],0,1) 
train <- risk[which(choose <=0.75),]   
test <- risk[which(choose >0.75),]     

library(rpart)    
cart.o <- rpart(risk ~ marital_status+mortgage+loans+age+income,  
             data=train, method = "class")
```

However, I am getting following error:

> 'Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :    invalid 'envir' argument of
>   type 'character''

Can you guys please help in resolving this error?
Dataset used is : classifyrisk.txt
(Also available on github)(Not sure how to upload data file here)

Thanks..enter code here

Comment: what do you get if you type `sapply(train, class)` ?

Comment: For including data in R stack overflow questions, look up the `dput()` function and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for advice on how to include data and make questions reproducible.

Comment: Output for sapply(train,class) is as below:                                                                  y,3,34,other,28060.700000,bad loss    n,2,37,other,28009.340000,bad loss    n,2,29,other,27614.600000,bad loss 
                          "character"                           "character"                           "character" 
   n,2,28,other,26271.860000,bad loss    n,2,25,other,23888.300000,bad loss    n,2,41,other,35249.250000,bad loss 
                          "character"                           "character"                           "character"